# Nivo Slider - change Thumbnails for Text links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, nivo-slider

I really like this Nivo Slider: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/4/

However, instead of the thumbnails for navigation, I'd just like to use regular text links.

Is this easy to replace the thumbnails with text links?

I can do this easily enough in Google Chrome Developer Tools, but not sure where to begin in the Nivo Slider itself to make it permanent.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the slider is here http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

By the looks of it you have to set this!

controlNavThumbs: false

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Remember to accept as answer :) Glad to help out!